# How to select data which was added in last 10 second in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a update side bar which load first last 15 data at once,

So I use this query here:

```
$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

Now, I want to make a another query which only select new `parent_id` from updateside TABLE which was added last 10 second if found. And I will prepend it by ajax

How to do this php query

Comment: UH? if you got a timestamp or datetime field on db you can do it

Comment: Show your `updateside` table structure. There should be a timestamp or datetime field, what is store, when record added, and then you can create a query, what is check the date inserted.

Comment: I think you should pick the record id of last record and send it through ajax, and then you can simply pick records whose id is greater than the id sent through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'add_date' field on table updateside, use this.

> select * FROM updateside where add_date >= now() - interval 10 second

Comment: how to add this 'date >= now() - interval 10 second' here "SELECT parent_id FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' ORDER BY created DESC"

Answer (score 0):

select * FROM updateside ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15